# C#: Resetting the console color pallet after user has modified it

Tags: c#, colors, ascii, console-application

I'm working on creating an ASCII interface for a school project but I've run into a bit of an issue.

[Output & properties window for CMD |Screenshot|](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEG4a.jpg)

I originally modified the colours to be a bit easier on the eyes and be more aesthetically pleasing just because I tend to used that ol' cmd.exe a fair bit, but looks like it's come back to mess with me. Soft darkish blue with canary yellow text, looked alright. Apparently Console.ConsoleColor takes all of its colours from the colours I modified in the cmd.exe properties window. NO GOOD! I don't see why the two are separate :/

Anyone out there know a way to override this pallet? I'm hoping for something that would like me set the RGB in the code but if there's a way to access the System.Drawing.Color pallet that would be kickass!

I'm pretty new at programming here so I would very much appreciate a well explained answer, I'm not picky however :P

Here's the code that created the output above:

```
//show a title
        Console.Title = "Contact Book";

        //set up the console window all nice like   
        Console.SetWindowSize(80, 50);

        Console.SetBufferSize(80, 50);

        //my attempt to reset the colors :( does not work
        Console.ResetColor();

        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

        Console.Clear();

        //write some stuff... :/
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Console.LargestWindowWidth, Console.LargestWindowHeight);

        Console.WriteLine("11111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666667777777777888888888889999999999900000000000");

        for (int i = 2; i != 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
        }
```

PS: Would have embedded the image but this is my first time on stackoverflow.com so I have no rep :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all very much by design.  A console app can only ever display 16 distinct colors.  The shortcut properties allows a user to customize those colors, much like the Display applet in Control Panel allows her to change the Windows theme colors for a GUI app.  Overriding the user's preference is almost never not a mistake.

But you can on Vista and Win7 by pinvoking the SetConsoleScreenBufferEx() API function.  Boilerplate code (in C) is in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/f8fb4005-475d-4edc-99b3-b74519ce5a4e), visit pinvoke.net for the declarations you'll need.

Comment: PInvoke eh? Alright! New toy!

I didn't think about how you pretty much never want to override a user's preference but in this case I'm working on an game like that of the ASCII days and it just makes more sense to have a dependable set of colours to be able to work with. Just for the sake of the designer being able to deliver a consistent experience across multiple computers. (This does make me think that maybe I should have an option to enable/disable the override somewhere)

I'd upvote this but alas, I am but a noob. Thanks a lot :)